# How to get the total amount of contributors to a GitHub repository?

Tags: python, python-requests, github-api

How can I get the total amount of contributors of a GitHub repository? The API makes it quite difficult because of the pagination.

This is what I tried so far using Python:

```
contributors = "https://api.github.com/repos/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site/contributors"
x = requests.get(contributors)
y = json.loads(x.text)
len(y) # maximum 30 because of pagination
```

Comment: `/repos/:owner/:repo/stats/contributors` ([documented here](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/)) has weekly statistics, but if you're interested in the overall total, that isn't a big help, either.

Comment: Maybe the [GraphQL API](https://developer.github.com/v4/) allows such aggregation. Might be worth investigating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a last resort you can scrape required value from [GitHub HTML page](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site) ([lxml.html lib](https://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) required):

```
import requests
from lxml import html

r = requests.get('https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site')
xpath = '//span[contains(@class, "num") and following-sibling::text()[normalize-space()="contributors"]]/text()'
contributors_number = int(html.fromstring(r.text).xpath(xpath)[0].strip())
print(contributors_number)
# 338
```

Comment: Well know I'm wondering how to get the amount of commits. I'm experimenting around but I don't get it.

Comment: @Max , try to replace `"contributors"` with `"commits"` in `xpath` and use `commits_number = int(html.fromstring(r.text).xpath(xpath)[0].strip().replace(',', ''))`

Comment: Nice! Thanks once again.

Comment: I just ran into it so I share it: Sometimes it happens that a repository has more than 1000 contributors and the number will include a comma again, so the replace() method has to be used again to get rid of it.

Comment: @Max , yes, right, In case contributors number is >999 , then we can't convert string into integer because of that comma. So it should be removed